# Is there a way I can transfer everything from one villager to a new one?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I don't like the way my villager looks (made him before I found a face guide). I would start new but I've invested so much time and payed off a bunch of my home loans. Is there a way I can make a new person and transfer my house and items?

Answer (score 1):

You can transfer your items, but not your house. The house is tied to a specific character, and can only be deleted by deleting the character. The items are not bound to any character, and can be picked up by other characters as long as they are not in your house.

If the character in question is mayor, you won't be able to delete him/her. The only way to remove the first character is to restart the town. You can transfer items to another copy of the game, restart the town, and transfer them back if you aren't too attached to your existing town.

Comment: This answer may be a bit misleading. Catalogs do not transfer. If OP resets the character they loose everything, house, catalog, etc... You're starting from scratch. If the character is not a Mayor, you still loose the catalog and house, but you can preserve any items held in inventory by giving them to the Mayor or one of the other player slots to hold temporarily.